# What is the charge of Silicon dioxide?

Tags: bond, formal-charge

What is the charge of Silicon dioxide ions? I can't find it anywhere.

It seems to be 0?

Also is there anywhere I can find these on my own?

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question is. Usually one talks about a formal charge on a particular *atom*. Worse, $\ce{SiO2}$ isn't an isolated molecule - it's a network solid. (Actually, it's many types of network solids.)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Sorry I meant the ions

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Also side question, what is more common Fe2 or Fe3?

Comment: @Thursday SiO2 isn't an ionic substance. Each individual unit is polar, though, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Like what @GeoffHutchison said,

$\ce{SiO2}$ is not an ion. It is a network solid. Its net charge is zero.

From charge balance, since oxygen holds a -2 formal charge, then silicon must hold a +4 formal charge in order to balance out. $(+4) + (+2 \times -2) = 0$